# Should I post questions about solutions to standardized tests on Stack Exchange?

Tags: discussion, community-standards

I have been going over practice test questions for the SAS Base certification.

Sometimes, while going through various practice questions I have collected from random websites, I get seriously stumped or have questions about some of the more subtle aspects of the (given) solutions.

I want to ask about this stuff on Stack Overflow, however, I get a little creeped out.

What if these are official questions that have been smuggled out of the testing sites (I have found these questions on random blogs -- who knows where they come from)?

I suppose I wonder what the ethical, legal, etc. ramifications about this may be.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

If you post it, you are claiming that you have the legal right to license it. Do you?

Comment: I see, thank you.  Can you provide me with a link to a SO resource that explains this restriction a little more in depth?

Comment: Look at the bottom of this page: user contributions licensed under cc by-sa 3.0 with attribution required